# PIVOT multiple columns not considering aggregate result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to PIVOT multiple columns of data. Here is the query I tried.

```
;WITH CTE(Project,Cost,spc,CostType)
AS
(
SELECT 'Project 1', 100 ,103,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 1', 12  ,15,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 45  ,22,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 2   ,37,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 33  ,46,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 3', 42  ,11,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 4', 57  ,5,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 5', 22  ,77,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 5', 17  ,9,'External' 
)
SELECT Project,
        ISNULL([Internal],0) AS [Internal],
        ISNULL([External],0) AS [External],
        ISNULL([Internal2],0) AS [InternalSPC],
        ISNULL([External2],0) AS [ExternalSPC]
FROM
(
SELECT Project,
        Cost,
        spc,
        CostType,
        CostType+'2' as CostType2
from CTE
)AS SRC
PIVOT
(
SUM(Cost) FOR CostType IN ([Internal],[External])
)
AS PVT

PIVOT
(
SUM(spc) FOR CostType2 IN ([Internal2],[External2])
)
AS PVT
```

The result am getting is as follows

[image]

But the expected result  is

```
 Project     Internal     External     InternalSPC     ExternalSPC
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Project 1     100          12          103                15
 Project 2     78           2            68               37
 Project 3     0            42          0                 11
 Project 4     57           0             5               0
 Project 5     22          17          77               9
```

I didnt understand the issue with my query

**Edit based on an answer**

In first answer for this its using grouping. But the strange thing is if we consider only one column its working as we expected without grouping.
Check this query where Im considering only one column

```
;WITH CTE(Project,Cost,spc,CostType)
AS
(
SELECT 'Project 1', 100 ,103,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 1', 12  ,15,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 45  ,22,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 2   ,37,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 33  ,46,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 3', 42  ,11,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 4', 57  ,5,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 5', 22  ,77,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 5', 17  ,9,'External' 
)
SELECT Project,
        ISNULL([Internal],0) AS [Internal],
        ISNULL([External],0) AS [External]
FROM
(
SELECT Project,
        Cost,
        CostType
from CTE
)AS SRC
PIVOT
(
SUM(Cost) FOR CostType IN ([Internal],[External])
)
AS PVT
```

The result of the above query is as follows

[image]
I didnt understand why it works fine for 1 column pivot without grouping.

Comment: I address the problem with multi-pivoting at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: use group by with project column and sum agggregation

```
;WITH CTE(Project,Cost,spc,CostType)
AS
(
SELECT 'Project 1', 100 ,103,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 1', 12  ,15,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 45  ,22,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 2   ,37,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 33  ,46,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 3', 42  ,11,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 4', 57  ,5,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 5', 22  ,77,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 5', 17  ,9,'External' 
)
SELECT Project,
        sum(ISNULL([Internal],0)) AS [Internal],
        sum(ISNULL([External],0)) AS [External],
        sum(ISNULL([Internal2],0)) AS [InternalSPC],
        sum(ISNULL([External2],0)) AS [ExternalSPC]
FROM
(
SELECT Project,
        Cost,
        spc,
        CostType,
        CostType+'2' as CostType2
from CTE
)AS SRC
PIVOT
(
SUM(Cost) FOR CostType IN ([Internal],[External])
)
AS PVT

PIVOT
(
SUM(spc) FOR CostType2 IN ([Internal2],[External2])
)
AS PVT
group by Project
```

Comment: Don't just write "try this". Explain *what you have changed*. Explain *why it should/will fix the problem*.

Comment: @fa06 Thanks a lot. But can you please check the modified question if you dont mind. Its working fine without grouping for one column pivot. So why its not working for 2 columns without grouping

Comment: when you've more that one pivot you need to use group by, other than one is fine

Answer (score 1):

I would first `unpivot` the data so that it's all of the values are in one column, combine another pair of columns so that we have distinct names and then we can apply a single `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH CTE(Project,Cost,spc,CostType)
AS
(
SELECT 'Project 1', 100 ,103,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 1', 12  ,15,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 45  ,22,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 2   ,37,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 2', 33  ,46,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 3', 42  ,11,'External' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 4', 57  ,5,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 5', 22  ,77,'Internal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Project 5', 17  ,9,'External' 
), Combined as (
select
    Project, CostType + Nature as Title, Value
from
    CTE
        unpivot (Value for Nature in (Cost,spc)) u
)
select
 Project,
        ISNULL([InternalCost],0) AS [Internal],
        ISNULL([ExternalCost],0) AS [External],
        ISNULL([InternalSpc],0) AS [InternalSPC],
        ISNULL([ExternalSpc],0) AS [ExternalSPC]
from
    Combined
        pivot (SUM(Value) for Title in 
              (InternalCost,ExternalCost,InternalSpc,ExternalSpc)) u
```

The main reason your attempt doesn't work is because `PIVOT` applies non-obvious grouping<sup>1</sup>. So in your first `PIVOT`, the distinctly different values in the `Spc` columns means that you don't just produce a single output row for each `Project` value.

So I usually try to reduce these sorts of queries down to applying a single `PIVOT` that only works with the columns of interest.

---

<sup>1</sup>By which I mean, I'd much prefer an explicit `GROUP BY` syntax for `PIVOT` which would make it obvious which columns are being used for grouping, rather than it being "all columns in the current result set not mentioned in the `PIVOT` clause". But even with such syntax, it would just have highlighted (if you could just group by `Project`) that `Spc` was no longer available for the second `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by using single *conditional* aggregation query :

```
select Project, 
       sum(case when costtype = 'Internal' then Cost else 0 end) as Internal,
       sum(case when costtype = 'External' then Cost else 0 end) as External,
       sum(case when costtype = 'Internal' then spc else 0 end) as InternalSPC ,
       sum(case when costtype = 'External' then spc else 0 end) as ExternalSPC 
from cte c
group by Project;
```